# Java Interfaces and Memory Allocation

Tags: java, memory-management, interface, object-reference

Consider:

```
public SomeClass implements SomeInterface{...}

SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();

SomeInterface x = obj;
```

I am trying to relate line 3 to my very basic understanding of memory management.
I know the memory location represented by "obj" just contains a pointer to the memory location of SomeClass. Assuming I am using a 64bit JVM, then up to 64 bits are allocated for the "obj" pointer. What is created in memory when the JRE implements x? Is it just a 64bit pointer to SomeClass?

Comment: Yes. x is also just a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object reference takes up the same amount of memory, no matter how you declare it.

So `x` and `obj` are two distict references, which just happen to point at the same thing.

Comment: *Every object reference takes up the same amount of memory*. Is this strictly true under CompressedOops? https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops

Comment: @NPE Well, if you go down deep enough, many easy truths don't hold. Like, objects in the real world don't really have color etc. But I think for the sake of the question, my statement is true.

Comment: What then is the purpose of declaring x as type SomeInterface? Why not just say SomeClass x = obj; Are the two statements doing the exact same thing?

Comment: @James Rogers Generally, you want to declare objects using their interface type, because then you could swap the implementation class to some other class without changing the code (e.g. a `HashSet` and a `TreeSet`are both `Set`s). That's a different question though.

Comment: @Thomas, if I understand you correctly you are saying the advantage of an interface is that I can do this? SomeOtherClass implements SomeInterface{...}      SomeOtherClass someOtherObj = new SomeOtherClass();     x = someOtherObj;

Answer (score 1):

In simple sentence references take same memory in Java however declared.

[Stack and Heap for Memory Allocation](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-stack-heap.html) this will help you understand in detail how it

[image]
works.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual memory overhead, the `SomeInterface` declaration is at this point simply a language construct, typing `x` for later checking by the compiler.

Comment: Are you saying that `x` occupies zero amount of storage, including no storage for the reference itself?

Comment: No, there is storage for the variable, but it's not different from any other reference. The fact that it's an interface doesn't change that.